Table View not showing content
i hope this isnt a stupid question.  i am VERY VERY new to ios and im just trying to figure things out here.
I have a ContentView.swift file that displays the data im looking for in the preview pane.  i cant seem to figure out how to get it on the actual screen.  i feel ive read you have to do it through a "Table View" but cant seem to figure out all out.  is there a way to get the output of the .swift file to the screen?  is Table View even the right answer?  my view is pointing at the correct class.  i just get a white screen when i actually simulate it.
here is the screen that makes the preview just fine:
// ContentView.swift

import SwiftUI

 
struct TourContentView: View {

    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView{

            List{
                ForEach(viewModel.courses,id: \.self) { tournament in

                    HStack {

                        Image("")

                           .frame(width: 5, height: 120)

                           .background(Color.orange)

                        VStack {

                            Text(tournament.name).bold()

                            Text(tournament.dates)
                            Text(tournament.datee)
                            Text(tournament.location)
                              //  .bold()
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(0)
                }
            }

            .navigationTitle("Tournaments")
            .onAppear {
                viewModel.fetch()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TourContentView()      

    }
}

lots of research, im over looking something obviously

Your code is SwiftUI. You should add that tag to your question.
You defined a custom View of type TourContentView. You only show that file. If you don't add a TourContentView to your app's content view, it won't appear on screen.
A typical SwiftUI created with the Xcode template has a view of type ContentView, and you would usually add your custom view(s) to that view:
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // Put your view here:
            TourContentView()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

Alternately, you could make your TourContentView the root view for your app:
@main
struct ViewTestApp: App { // This will be your app name
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            TourContentView() // <- Replace `ContentView` with your View type. 
        }
    }
}


Duncan,  thank you for the reply and help.  i appreciate it.  when you say add app's content view you are refurring to a "Table View"  on top of the view correct?  if that is what you mean, i did add one.  just cant seem to do anything with it.  if not, then i can research more if that is not what you are talking about.  i also added it under my swift file that has the @main tag but get an error:

No, am talking about your app's content view. Upload your entire project to Github and post a link to it in your question, and add a comment telling us that you've posted it.

(I showed 2 different ways you could link your custom TourContentView into your application. You ether need to invoke your TourContentView from within your ContentView (as in the first snippet I posted) or  in your app's body (instead of the default ContentView (as in the 2nd snippet I posted)
